# Record something, add effects and save it in base64

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

Basically that's it, Im trying to record audio, using the Web Audio API and tuna.js or pizzicato.js add some effects and save it into a server in base64.

The problem is, using recorder.js the audio is save the record in a blob object, after that I can transform it into a base64 (not editable) with the FileReader(). I've trying add effects to the blob:url, and works perfectly, but I cant transform the edited audio into base64.

```js
recorder.addEventListener( "dataAvailable", function(e){
  var fileName = new Date().toISOString() + "." + e.detail.type.split("/")[1];
  var url = URL.createObjectURL( e.detail );
  var audiob = "";
 var reader = new window.FileReader();
 reader.readAsDataURL(e.detail); //e.detail 
 reader.onloadend = function() {
    base64data = reader.result;
    audiob = base64data;  
}
```

```js
e.detail -> 
Blob {size: 28278, type: "audio/wav"}
  size:28278
  type:"audio/wav"
  __proto__:Blob
```

Any help? :)

PD: Sorry about my english, I know it sucks

Comment: Can you explain what is the problem ? Do you see an error ? What do you expect and what do you get? What is the content of `base64data` ?